# Python type signature for builtin api

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

Python typing makes progress.
There is a tool, such us mypy, for transforming application code to insert type signatures.

I check python 3.12 and `inspect.signature()` returns no trace of types for builtin function `pickle.dumps`

```
Python 3.12.0a6 (main, Mar  7 2023, 21:53:22) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> import pickle
>>> inspect.signature(pickle.dumps)
<Signature (obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True, buffer_callback=None)>
>>> inspect.signature(pickle.dumps).return_annotation
<class 'inspect._empty'>
```

Is there a project trying to do best effort in covering Builtin Python API with type signatures?

Comment: mypy vendors [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/) which does exactly that

Comment: @Clasherkasten important to note, this won't affect `inspect.signature`.